# Mixing RazorEngine Syntax with javascript

Tags: razor, razorengine

On my view page, I want to display some buttons if certain conditions are met, the code goes like this:

```
<script>
var html = "";
html += "<button>View Member</button>";
@if (Model.HasPrivilage["UPDATE_MEMBER"] == true) {
    html += "<button>Add Member</button>";
    html += "<button>Remove Member</button>";
}
$("#container").html(html);
</script>
```

However it throws TemplateCompilationException exception, it seems that I have to do something to wrap up javascript texts, how can I improve my code to make it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The Code inside the if Statement gets Interpreted as C#. You need to say that it is a string by using @: and than write the code.

So change the if like this

```
@if(...){
    @:html += ....
    @:html += ...
)
```